# Не работает scroll только в браузере гугл хром

Tags: google-chrome, прокрутка

Сайт http://hitgarden.ru/ . В самом теге боди в  main-style.css не нашел overflow hidden может быть проблема в чем то другом . Так бы скролинг и в других браузерах не работал ведь так?

к body parallax-slider нашел событие скролл  может тут ,что то не так `
            //------------------ window scroll event -------------//
            $(window).on('scroll',
                function(){
                    mainScrollFunction();
                }
            ).trigger('scroll');

```
        //------------------ window resize event -------------//
        $(window).on("resize",
            function(){
                mainResizeFunction();
            }
        )
    }`
```

А вот весь скрипт parallaxslider.js `(function($){
     $.fn.parallaxSlider=function(o){

```
    var options = {
        prevButton: $('.prevButton')
    ,   nextButton: $('.nextButton')
    ,   duration: 1000
    ,   autoSwitcher: true
    ,   autoSwitcherDelay: 7000
    ,   slider_navs: true
    ,   scrolling_description: false
    ,   slider_pagination: 'buttons_pagination'
    ,   animateLayout: 'zoom-fade-eff' //simple-fade-eff, zoom-fade-eff, slide-top-eff
    ,   parallaxEffect: 'parallax_effect_normal'
    ,   parallaxInvert: false
    ,   liteMode: false
    }
    $.extend(options, o);

    var 
        _this = $(this)
    ,   _window = $(window)
    ,   _document = $(document)
    ,   ImgIdCounter = 0
    ,   previewArray = []
    ,   isPreviewLoading = false
    ,   isPreviewAnimate = false
    ,   intervalSwitcher
    ,   parsedArray
    ,   parallax = true
    ,   parallaxType = 'parallax_normal'
    ,   _baseHeight
    ,   _thisOffsetTop = _this.offset().top
    ,   _thisHeight = _this.height()
    ,   _windowWidth = _window.width()
    ,   _windowHeight = _window.height()
    ,   itemLength = 0
    ,   bufferRatio 
    ;

    var
        img
    ,   imgBlock
    ,   mainImageHolder
    ,   primaryImageHolder
    ,   secondaryHolder
    ,   mainCaptionHolder
    ,   primaryCaption
    ,   secondaryCaption
    ,   mainCaptionHolderContainer
    ,   previewSpinner
    ,   parallaxPrevBtn
    ,   parallaxNextBtn
    ,   slidesCounterList
    ,   paralaxSliderPagination
    ;

    //--------------- Init ------------------//
    init();
    function init(){
        parsedArray = [];
        $('ul li', _this).each(
            function(){
                parsedArray.push([$(this).attr('data-preview'), $(this).attr('data-thumb-url'), $(this).html()]);
            }
        )

        //  holder erase
        _this.html('');
        _this.addClass(options.animateLayout);

        //  preview holder build
        imgBlocksStructure = !options.liteMode ? "<div id='mainImageHolder'><div class='primaryHolder'><div class='imgBlock'></div></div><div class='secondaryHolder'><div class='imgBlock'></div></div></div>" : "<div id='mainImageHolder'><div class='primaryHolder'><img class='imgBlock' src='' alt=''/></div><div class='secondaryHolder'><img class='imgBlock' src='' alt=''/></div></div>"; 
        _this.append(imgBlocksStructure);
        mainImageHolder = $('#mainImageHolder');
        primaryImageHolder = $('> .primaryHolder', mainImageHolder);
        secondarImageHolder = $('> .secondaryHolder', mainImageHolder);
        imgBlock = $('.imgBlock', mainImageHolder);

         //  caption holder build
        _this.append("<div id='mainCaptionHolder'><div class='container'><div class='primaryCaption'></div><div class='secondaryCaption'></div></div></div>");
        mainCaptionHolder = $('#mainCaptionHolder');
        primaryCaption = $('.primaryCaption', mainCaptionHolder);
        secondaryCaption = $('.secondaryCaption', mainCaptionHolder);
        mainCaptionHolderContainer = $('>.container', mainCaptionHolder);

        //  controls build
        _this.append("<div class='controlBtn parallaxPrevBtn'><div class='innerBtn icon-angle-left'></div><div class='slidesCounter'></div></div><div class='controlBtn parallaxNextBtn'><div class='innerBtn icon-angle-right'></div><div class='slidesCounter'></div></div>");
        parallaxPrevBtn = $('.parallaxPrevBtn', _this);
        parallaxNextBtn = $('.parallaxNextBtn', _this);

        //  fullpreview pagination build
        _this.append("<div id='paralaxSliderPagination'><ul></ul></div>");
        paralaxSliderPagination = $('#paralaxSliderPagination');

        slidesCounterList = $('.slidesCounter', _this);

        //  preview loader build
        _this.append("<div id='previewSpinner'><span></span></div>");
        previewSpinner = $('#previewSpinner');

        _this.on("reBuild",
            function(e,d){
                setBuilder(d);
            }
        )

        _this.on("switchNext",
            function(e){
                nextSwither();
            }
        )

        _this.on("switchPrev",
            function(e){
                prevSwither();
            }
        )

        setBuilder({'urlArray':parsedArray});

        if(!options.slider_navs){
            parallaxPrevBtn.remove();
            parallaxNextBtn.remove();
        }
        if(options.slider_pagination == 'none_pagination'){
            paralaxSliderPagination.remove();
        }

        if(options.liteMode) options.parallaxEffect = 'parallax_none';

        switch (options.parallaxEffect) {
            case 'parallax_effect_low':
                if(!options.parallaxInvert){
                    parallaxType = 'parallax_normal';
                } else {
                    parallaxType = 'parallax_invert';
                }

                bufferRatio = 3;

                break

            case 'parallax_effect_normal':
                if(!options.parallaxInvert){
                    parallaxType = 'parallax_normal';
                } else {
                    parallaxType = 'parallax_invert';
                }

                 bufferRatio = 2.25;

                break

            case 'parallax_effect_high':
                if(!options.parallaxInvert){
                    parallaxType = 'parallax_normal';
                } else {
                    parallaxType = 'parallax_invert';
                }

                bufferRatio = 1.5;

                break

            case 'parallax_effect_fixed':
                if($.browser.msie){
                    parallax = false;
                    imgBlock.css({backgroundAttachment:'fixed'});
                } else {
                    parallaxType = 'parallax_fixes';
                }

                bufferRatio = 1;

                break

            default:
                parallax = false;
                parallaxType = 'parallax_none';

                break
        }

        _baseHeight = getBaseHeight();

        addEventsFunction();
        autoSwitcher();
    }

    //------------------------- set Builder -----------------------------//
    function setBuilder(dataObj){ 
        currIndex = 0;
        ImgIdCounter = 0;
        previewArray = [];
        previewArray = dataObj.urlArray;
        itemLength = previewArray.length;

        $(">ul", paralaxSliderPagination).empty();

        switch (options.slider_pagination) {
            case 'buttons_pagination':
                paralaxSliderPagination.addClass('buttons_pagination');
                for (var i = 0; i < itemLength; i++) {
                    $(">ul", paralaxSliderPagination).append("<li></li>");
                };

                break

            case 'images_pagination':
                paralaxSliderPagination.addClass('images_pagination');
                for (var i = 0; i < itemLength; i++) {
                    $(">ul", paralaxSliderPagination).append("<li><img src='"+previewArray[i][1]+"'></li>");
                };

                 break
        }

        if(itemLength==1){
            paralaxSliderPagination.remove();
            parallaxPrevBtn.remove();
            parallaxNextBtn.remove();
        }

        imageSwitcher(0);
        addEventsPagination();
    }

    function autoSwitcher(){
        if(options.autoSwitcher){
            if(itemLength>1){
                intervalSwitcher = setInterval(function(){
                    nextSwither();
                }, options.autoSwitcherDelay);
            }
        }
    }

    //---------------  addEvents  ----------------------//
    function addEventsPagination(){
        $(">ul >li", paralaxSliderPagination).on("click",
            function(){
                if((!isPreviewLoading) && (!isPreviewAnimate) && ($(this).index() !== ImgIdCounter)){
                    clearInterval(intervalSwitcher);
                    ImgIdCounter = $(this).index();
                    imageSwitcher(ImgIdCounter);
                }
            }
        )
    }

    function addEventsFunction(){
        //--------------- controls events ----------------------//
        options.prevButton.on("click",
            function(){
                clearInterval(intervalSwitcher);
                prevSwither();
            }
        )
        options.nextButton.on("click",
            function(){
                clearInterval(intervalSwitcher);
                nextSwither(); 
            }
        )
        parallaxPrevBtn.on("click",
            function(){
                clearInterval(intervalSwitcher);
                prevSwither();
            }
        )
        parallaxNextBtn.on("click",
            function(){
                clearInterval(intervalSwitcher);
                nextSwither();
            }
        )

        //--------------- keyboard events ----------------------//
        _window.on("keydown",
            function(eventObject){
                switch (eventObject.keyCode){
                    case 37:
                        clearInterval(intervalSwitcher);
                        prevSwither();
                    break
                    case 39:
                         clearInterval(intervalSwitcher);
                        nextSwither();
                    break
                }
            }
        )

        //------------------ window scroll event -------------//
        $(window).on('scroll',
            function(){
                mainScrollFunction();
            }
        ).trigger('scroll');

        //------------------ window resize event -------------//
        $(window).on("resize",
            function(){
                mainResizeFunction();
            }
        )
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    function prevSwither(){
        if(!isPreviewLoading && !isPreviewAnimate){
            if(ImgIdCounter > 0){
                ImgIdCounter--;
            }else{
                ImgIdCounter = itemLength-1;
            }
                imageSwitcher(ImgIdCounter);
        }
    }
    function nextSwither(){
        if(!isPreviewLoading && !isPreviewAnimate){
            if(ImgIdCounter < itemLength-1){
                ImgIdCounter++;
            }else{
                ImgIdCounter = 0;
            }
            imageSwitcher(ImgIdCounter);
        }
    }

    //------------------------- main Swither ----------------------------//
    function imageSwitcher(currIndex){ 
        slidesCounterList.text((currIndex+1) + '/'+itemLength);
        $(">ul >li", paralaxSliderPagination).removeClass('active').eq(currIndex).addClass('active');

        objectCssTransition(primaryImageHolder, 0, 'ease');
        primaryImageHolder.addClass('animateState');

        primaryCaption.html(previewArray[currIndex][2]);
        objectCssTransition(primaryCaption, 0, 'ease');
        primaryCaption.addClass('animateState');

        isPreviewLoading = true;
        isPreviewAnimate = true;
        previewSpinner.css({display:'block'}).stop().fadeTo(300, 1);

        img = new Image();
        img.src = previewArray[currIndex][0];

        img.onload = function () {
            isPreviewLoading = false;
            previewSpinner.stop().fadeTo(300, 0, function(){ $(this).css({display:'none'}); })

            primaryImage = $('>.imgBlock', primaryImageHolder);
            if(!options.liteMode){ primaryImage.css('background-image', 'url(' + img.src + ')'); } else { primaryImage.attr('src', img.src); }
            objectResize(primaryImage, _windowWidth, _baseHeight);

            objectCssTransition(primaryImageHolder, options.duration, 'outCubic');
            primaryImageHolder.removeClass('animateState');
            objectCssTransition(secondarImageHolder, options.duration, 'outCubic');
            secondarImageHolder.addClass('animateState');

            objectCssTransition(primaryCaption, options.duration, 'outCubic');
            primaryCaption.removeClass('animateState');
            objectCssTransition(secondaryCaption, options.duration, 'outCubic');
            secondaryCaption.addClass('animateState');

            mainCaptionHolderContainer.height(primaryCaption.height());

            setTimeout(
                function(){                        
                    secondarImage = $('>.imgBlock', secondarImageHolder);
                    if(!options.liteMode){ secondarImage.css('background-image', 'url(' + img.src + ')'); } else { secondarImage.attr('src', img.src); }      
                    objectResize(secondarImage, _windowWidth, _baseHeight);

                    objectCssTransition(secondarImageHolder, 0, 'ease');
                    secondarImageHolder.removeClass('animateState');

                    secondaryCaption.html(previewArray[currIndex][2]);
                    objectCssTransition(secondaryCaption, 0, 'ease');
                    secondaryCaption.removeClass('animateState');

                    isPreviewAnimate = false;
                }, options.duration
            )
        }
    }

    //----------------------------------------------------//
    function objectCssTransition(obj, duration, ease){
        var durationValue;

        if(duration !== 0){
            durationValue = duration/1000;
        }else{
            durationValue = 0
        }

        switch(ease){
            case 'ease':
                    obj.css({"-webkit-transition":"all "+durationValue+"s ease", "-moz-transition":"all "+durationValue+"s ease", "-o-transition":"all "+durationValue+"s ease", "transition":"all "+durationValue+"s ease"});
            break;
            case 'outSine':
                obj.css({"-webkit-transition":"all "+durationValue+"s cubic-bezier(0.470, 0.000, 0.745, 0.715)", "-moz-transition":"all "+durationValue+"s cubic-bezier(0.470, 0.000, 0.745, 0.715)", "-o-transition":"all "+durationValue+"s cubic-bezier(0.470, 0.000, 0.745, 0.715)", "transition":"all "+durationValue+"s cubic-bezier(0.470, 0.000, 0.745, 0.715)"});
            break;
            case 'outCubic':
                obj.css({"-webkit-transition":"all "+durationValue+"s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000)", "-moz-transition":"all "+durationValue+"s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000)", "-o-transition":"all "+durationValue+"s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000)", "transition":"all "+durationValue+"s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000)"});
            break;
            case 'outExpo':
                obj.css({"-webkit-transition":"all "+durationValue+"s cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000)", "-moz-transition":"all "+durationValue+"s cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000)", "-o-transition":"all "+durationValue+"s cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000)", "transition":"all "+durationValue+"s cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000)"});
            break;
            case 'outBack':
                obj.css({"-webkit-transition":"all "+durationValue+"s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275)", "-moz-transition":"all "+durationValue+"s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275)", "-o-transition":"all "+durationValue+"s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275)", "transition":"all "+durationValue+"s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275)"});
            break;
        }
    }

    //------------------------ Object resize ----------------------------//
    function objectResize(obj, baseWidth, baseHeight )
    {
        var imageRatio,
            originalImgWidth,
            originalImgHeight,
            newImgWidth,
            newImgHeight,
            newImgTop,
            newImgLeft;

        originalImgWidth = img.width;
        originalImgHeight = img.height;

        imageRatio = originalImgHeight/originalImgWidth;
        containerRatio = baseHeight/baseWidth;

        if(containerRatio > imageRatio){
            newImgHeight = baseHeight;
            newImgWidth = Math.round( (newImgHeight*originalImgWidth) / originalImgHeight );   
        }else{
            newImgWidth = baseWidth;
            newImgHeight = Math.round( (newImgWidth*originalImgHeight) / originalImgWidth );
        }

        newImgLeft=-(newImgWidth-baseWidth)*.5;
        newImgTop= -(newImgHeight-baseHeight)*.5;

        if(!options.liteMode){ obj.css({width: '100%', height: newImgHeight, marginTop: newImgTop}); } else { obj.css({width: newImgWidth, height: newImgHeight, marginTop: newImgTop, marginLeft: newImgLeft}); }
    }

    //------------------- main window scroll function -------------------//
    function mainScrollFunction(){
         if(parallax || options.scrolling_description && !options.liteMode){

             var _documentScrollTop
             ,   startScrollTop
             ,   endScrollTop
             ;

             _documentScrollTop = _document.scrollTop();
             _thisOffsetTop = _this.offset().top;

             startScrollTop = _documentScrollTop + _windowHeight;
             endScrollTop = _documentScrollTop - _thisHeight;

             if((startScrollTop > _thisOffsetTop) && (endScrollTop < _thisOffsetTop)){  

                 y = _documentScrollTop - _thisOffsetTop;

                 if(parallax){
                     if(!options.parallaxInvert) {
                         newPositionTop =  parseInt(y / bufferRatio);
                     } else {
                         if(_thisOffsetTop < Math.abs(_windowHeight-_thisHeight)){
                             newPositionTop = -parseInt(y / bufferRatio) - parseInt(_thisOffsetTop / bufferRatio);
                         } else{
                             newPositionTop = -parseInt(y / bufferRatio) - parseInt(_windowHeight / bufferRatio)
                         }
                     }

                     mainImageHolder.css({ top: newPositionTop + 'px' });   
                 }

                 if(options.scrolling_description){
                     description_opacity = (1-(y / _thisHeight)).toFixed(2); 
                     if(description_opacity < 1) mainCaptionHolder.css('opacity', description_opacity);

                     description_offset = parseInt(y/2.5);
                     if(description_offset > 0) {
                         mainCaptionHolder.css('top', description_offset);
                     } else {
                         mainCaptionHolder.css('top', '0px');   
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
    }

    //------------------- main window resize function -------------------//
    function mainResizeFunction(){
        _windowWidth = _window.width();
        _windowHeight = _window.height();
        _thisWidth = _this.width();
        _thisHeight = _this.height();
        _thisOffsetTop = _this.offset().top;

        _baseHeight = getBaseHeight();
        objectResize(imgBlock, _thisWidth, _baseHeight);
        mainScrollFunction();
    }

    //------------------- get heigth function -------------------//
    function getBaseHeight(){
        switch (parallaxType) {
            case 'parallax_normal':
                if(_thisOffsetTop < (_windowHeight-_thisHeight)){
                   baseHeight = _thisHeight + parseInt(_thisOffsetTop/bufferRatio); 
                } else {
                   baseHeight = _thisHeight + parseInt((_windowHeight - _thisHeight)/bufferRatio);
                }                   
                break

            case 'parallax_invert':
                if(_thisOffsetTop < Math.abs(_windowHeight-_thisHeight)){
                   baseHeight = _thisHeight + parseInt((_thisOffsetTop + _thisHeight)/bufferRatio); 
                } else {
                   baseHeight = _thisHeight + parseInt((_windowHeight + _thisHeight)/bufferRatio);
                }
                break

            case 'parallax_fixes':
                if((_thisOffsetTop + _thisHeight) < _windowHeight){
                    baseHeight = _thisOffsetTop + _thisHeight;
                } else {
                    baseHeight = _windowHeight;
                }
                break

            case 'parallax_none':
                baseHeight = _thisHeight;
                break
        }

        return baseHeight;
    }

    function toRadians (angle) {
        return angle * (Math.PI / 180);
    }        
}
```

})(jQuery)`

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66632/discussion-on-question-by-vladimir-sass---scroll----).